# JQuery('body').offset().top is off when using margin-top?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, if I understand http://api.jquery.com/offset correctly, $('body').offset() should return the position where the body is located, relative to the document. So inserting a `<p>`-tag at those coordinates on the page should put it at the very position of the body tag. But that is not what happens!

I tried this in both Safari 5.0.5 and Firefox 3.6 and both cases, the alert says "8" and the `<p>`-tag ends up 8 pixels from the top of the page, whereas the body tag starts 100 pixels further down on the page, as can be seen if inspecting using e.g firebug.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div style="margin-top:100px;background:yellow;">
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript"         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    alert(jQuery('body').offset().top);
    var myp = jQuery('<p>Top of body?</p>')
    myp.appendTo(jQuery('body'));
    myp.offset(jQuery('body').offset());
  </script>

</body>
```

So the question is: how am I supposed to do this so that the `<p>`-tag ends up in the body, and not at the top of the page, using .offset()?

Comment: I checked your code with firebug, but the body tag doesn't start 100 pixels further down. In fact it is the div layer. And because you haven't added the style attribute 'position:absolute' so the browser takes his default value. This is 'relative'.

Comment: Hmm.. Really? If I hold the mouse over the "<body>" string in the firebug-panel it highlights only the div, so I thought this meant that the body started there. I also tried adding a click handler to the body, e.g `jQuery('body').click(function(){alert("click");});`, which only fires when clicking inside the div.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think this is the reason for my confusion. Basically, I assumed the body started at the same place the div was included because any registered click handlers on the body would only fire when clicking on the div, not on the empty area above it created by the margin.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you'll find the body offset is equal to 0, that is because the body of the page is == you browsers viewport.

The reason Hello World is 100px down, is because you've applied a padding to it. Do you want your text "Top of body?" to appear below Hello World?..

If so, first give your div a class name (I've used hworld) and then append your var to it.

```
<div style="margin-top:100px;background:yellow;" class="hworld">
```

And:

```
myp.appendTo(jQuery('.hworld'));
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this is not quite what I was looking for. I was trying to add the "Top of body" at what I thought was the top of the body, namely the start of the div. But it turns out that that wasn't the case. I know now that the body starts at the begginning of the page. Now I am just confused as to why body-registered click handlers won't fire until I click inside the div.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something else interfering with your code.

It works fine in this fiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/7sGGq/